# How to fix issue with changing width computed by autolayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

**Problem:**

When you set width with autolayout as "mutipliedBy" relation to something or set to exact value (131 for example), it's getting changing while moving along X-axis.

**Example:**

I set width of the view equal to (131.0f). Then I move view along X-axis:

```
2016-06-10 16:58:30.961 {{6, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:31.095 {{5.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:31.212 {{5.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:31.362 {{5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:31.536 {{5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:31.692 {{3.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:31.791 {{3.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:31.833 {{3, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:31.864 {{3, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:31.930 {{2.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:31.978 {{2.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:32.045 {{2, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:32.129 {{2, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:32.195 {{1.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:32.330 {{1.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:32.516 {{0, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:32.648 {{-0.5, 40}, {131, 177.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:32.764 {{-0.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:32.812 {{-1, 40}, {131, 177.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:32.930 {{-1, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:33.194 {{-1.5, 40}, {131, 177.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:34.468 {{-1.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:34.760 {{-2, 40}, {131, 177.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:35.881 {{-2, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:36.166 {{-2.5, 40}, {131, 177.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:36.444 {{-3.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:37.230 {{-4, 40}, {131, 177.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:38.663 {{-4, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:39.847 {{-4.5, 40}, {131, 177.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:42.068 {{-4.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:42.498 {{-5, 40}, {131, 177.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:42.762 {{-5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:42.906 {{-5.5, 40}, {131, 177.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:43.096 {{-5.5, 40}, {130.5, 196.5}}
2016-06-10 16:58:43.232 {{-6, 40}, {131, 177.5}}
```

As you can see, width changes only when origin.x is negative.

**Possible solution:**

I can calculate width myself in updateConstraints (in my case it's acceptable), but maybe someone have better solution.

Comment: Well, this seems like a rounding error. `320 * 0.408 == 130.56`. Why such an "exotic" multiplier? I'd advise not to place/size views at half points, as it may look weird on odd scales (@1x, @3x).

Comment: @Losiowaty, according to AutoLayout docs, values should be rounded well. But I have tried with simple settings width - same problem.